# Is there a better way to display multivalue data as a column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpages

I have 4 audit fields in my notes database. They are multivalued and they each get a new entry when something on the form changes. I have an audit form which displays these fields in a columnar way. Almost like a view. Here is the code for the columns.

```
<xp:tr>
  <xp:td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">
  <xp:text escape="true" id="dspAuditWhen"></xp:text></xp:td>

  <xp:td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">
  <xp:text escape="true" id="dspAuditWho"></xp:text></xp:td>

  <xp:td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">
  <xp:text escape="true" id="dspAuditWhat"></xp:text></xp:td>

  <xp:td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">
  <xp:text escape="true" id="dspAuditValue"></xp:text></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
```

I populate these fields with a client sided "onClientLoad" event.

```
var auditWhen = XSP.getElementById("#{id:AuditWhen}").value.split(";");
XSP.getElementById("#{id:dspAuditWhen}").innerHTML = auditWhen.join("\n");

var auditWho = XSP.getElementById("#{id:AuditWho}").value.split(";");
for ( i = 0; i < auditWho.length ; i++) {auditWho[i] = auditWho[i].substr(0,20); }
var a=auditWho.join("\n");
XSP.getElementById("#{id:dspAuditWho}").innerHTML = auditWho.join("\n");

var auditWhat = XSP.getElementById("#{id:AuditWhat}").value.split(";");
var b=auditWhat.join("\n");
XSP.getElementById("#{id:dspAuditWhat}").innerHTML = auditWhat.join("\n");
```

Note a couple of things. I do not have the code in just yet for dspAuditValue. Also I'm controlling the length of auditWho. Also note that I have a variable "a",and "b" for debugging purposes.

Anyway this code works perfectly fine for the dspAuditWhen and dspAuditWho columns. For dspAuditWhat, they appear to be just separated by spaces, not newlines.

I compared "auditWhat" with "auditWho". "auditWhat" successfully split into an array just like "auditWho"

I compared "b" with "a". It too is a large string with each element separated by a \n.

I have verified that auditWhat is a multivalued list field in the notes client. (If it weren't, then my Notes client Audit form wouldn't be working.)

I see absolutely nothing wrong with this code. It's as if the web browser is saying "you get 2 columns with the data the way you want it and THAT'S IT!!!

Same behaviour in both IE & Firefox

Comment: jsfiddle.net with rendered HTML would be useful

Comment: Since these fields are being supplied by the server, I'm not sure how to get them into jsFiddle (Then again, I've never used jsfiddle, cursory glance doesn't give me many clues there.)

Comment: Load page in chrome, right click on data and choose inspect element. Choose a parent container, right click in debugger and choose copy html, paste into jsfiddle, remove sensitive data, save and post URL here

Comment: Thanks for pointing this page out to me! I'll be playing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\n isn't an HTML tag - it would be just like a carriage return in your HTML source.

Try joining with <br/> instead for a new line eg :

```
XSP.getElementById("#{id:dspAuditWhat}").innerHTML = auditWhat.join("<br/>");
```

Not sure why one column in particluar shopuld need special treatment though

Comment: Bingo! That worked! I'm sort of wondering why \n worked in the first 2 columns and not the 3rd too...

Comment: Well spotted, I did not even look in the mess of XSP calls

Comment: Yeah the 1st 2 columns thing is weird. All I can think of is there's a setting for how the element is rendered (as HTML vs. as plain text) but I'd expect to see something in the xml markup to signify that. Also this code is run client-side (presumably?) so that wouldn'a affect it anyway. I'm clutching at straws ..

Comment: ps. if you find out why the columns are behaving dofferently please post here - I'm intrigued!

Answer (score 1):

All values are in the same row of your table.
You can generate one row per value.
This can be done server side with something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="TestHistory"
            action="openDocument" />
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/histo.css" />
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
        var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex"
        value="#{document1.HistoDate}">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="header"
                escape="false">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            <table class="histo">
                <tr>
                    <th>When</th>
                    <th>Who</th>
                    <th>What</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                </tr>
            ]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>

            <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer"
                escape="false">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[</table>]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:this.facets>

        <xp:panel tagName="tr" styleClass="#{javascript: (rowIndex%2 ? 'odd' : 'even')}">
            <xp:text escape="true" tagName="td"
                value="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray('HistoDate')[rowIndex]}" />
            <xp:text escape="true" tagName="td"
                value="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray('HistoActor')[rowIndex]}" />
            <xp:text escape="true" tagName="td"
                value="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray('HistoAction')[rowIndex]}" />
            <xp:text escape="true" tagName="td"
                value="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray('HistoComment')[rowIndex]}" />
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:repeat>

</xp:view>
```

And some css like that :

```
table.histo {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.histo th, table.histo td {
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
table.histo th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
table.histo tr.even {
    background: #FFF;
}
table.histo tr.odd {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}
```